# How to save a spark rdd to an avro file

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, avro

I am trying to save an rdd to a file in avro format. This is how my code looks like:

```
val output = s"/test/avro/${date.toString(dayFormat)}"
  rmr(output)//deleteing the path
  rdd.coalesce(64).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    output,
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],
    classOf[PageViewEvent],
  classOf[AvroKeyValueOutputFormat[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable,PageViewEvent]],
    spark.hadoopConfiguration)
}
```

When I run this I get an error saying:

```
 Unsupported input type PageViewEvent
```

The type of the rdd is RDD[(Null,PageViewEvent)].
Can someone explain my what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to find a 'workaround'.

```
 val job = new Job(spark.hadoopConfiguration)
  AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, PageViewEvent.SCHEMA$)

  val output = s"/avro/${date.toString(dayFormat)}"
  rmr(output)
  rdd.coalesce(64).map(x => (new AvroKey(x._1), x._2))
    .saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    output,
    classOf[PageViewEvent],
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],
    classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[PageViewEvent]],
    job.getConfiguration)
```

this works fine. I don't try to use AvroKeyValueOutputFormat anymore. But I  think now i would be able to. The key change was to use AvroKey and to set OutputKeySchema.